# json decode call photo telegram api

Tags: php, json, decode, encode, telegram-bot

i want get photo file id.

```
file_get_contents('php://input'):

{
    "update_id": 399206890,
    "message": {
        "message_id": 149,
        "from": {
            "id": 81777999,
            "is_bot": false,
            "first_name": "@goldenguardbot",
            "last_name": "✅",
            "username": "amirntm",
            "language_code": "en-US"
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": 81777999,
            "first_name": "@goldenguardbot",
            "last_name": "✅",
            "username": "amirntm",
            "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1507643430,
        "photo": [
            {
                "file_id": "AgADBAADpaoxG6lZ6VIeePTlKxaJsl3X-RkABPbjyThHJgF7FLwBAAEC",
                "file_size": 1639,
                "file_path": "photos/file_4.jpg",
                "width": 90,
                "height": 72
            },
            {
                "file_id": "AgADBAADpaoxG6lZ6VIeePTlKxaJsl3X-RkABIrarvPZGVNGFrwBAAEC",
                "file_size": 22230,
                "width": 320,
                "height": 256
            },
            {
                "file_id": "AgADBAADpaoxG6lZ6VIeePTlKxaJsl3X-RkABKFhu79tL5EBF7wBAAEC",
                "file_size": 95422,
                "width": 800,
                "height": 640
            },
            {
                "file_id": "AgADBAADpaoxG6lZ6VIeePTlKxaJsl3X-RkABGzlLqe_Yv0PFbwBAAEC",
                "file_size": 172689,
                "width": 1160,
                "height": 928
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

i want file id how get it?
for example:

```
$update->message->photo->file_id;
```

Comment: `$update->message->photo[0]->file_id`

Comment: [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: If you dont understand json string notation, then always start by doing a `$t = json_decode($your_json_string); print_r($t);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "photo" section is an array.  Square brackets in JSON (`[]`) indicate an indexed array.  Curly braces (`{}`) indicate an object or associative array, depending on how you choose to parse it in PHP.

You don't mention which "file_id" you want, but assuming you want the first:

```
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo $update->message->photo[0]->file_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode it to PHP object/array, and get photos in `$update->message->photo`, that will be array of one photo in different resolution, the latest one always be largest, so you can use `end($photos)` to get it, and `file_id` is corresponding file identity.

Code example:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'): 
$update = json_decode($json);
$photos = $update->message->photo;
$photo = end($photo);
$file_id = $photo['file_id'];
```